# Table pagination in qooxdoo

Tags: qooxdoo

Best wishes to all helpers!
I searched hard but nobody could give answer about pagination for tables in qooxdoo. It is fantastic framework but why developers (and architectors) missed that not so deep and hard feature built in?

Thanks to anyone who will answer!

Oleg

Answer (score 0):

the qooxdoo table (lets hope you speak of the qx.Desktop layer) is a virtual widget and can handle a huge set of data without suffering any kind of performance decrease. Knowing that, there has been no need to add pagination to the table. If you don't want to load all the data at once, you can use the [Remote Table Model](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.model.Remote) to fetch only visible data. You can also check out the [demo of this model](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/demobrowser/index.html#table~Table_Remote_Model.html) to get an Idea of hot it is used.

Comment: When I continue your idea I should come to conclusion that I manually add controls like "page forward" and "page backward" and clear content of  grid then load new portion of data. Also I need to calculate number of rows and align height of grid. Is it correct?

Comment: @Олег Осколков you could do this, but why would you? Inherit from [Remote](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.model.Remote), override `_loadRowCount()` and `_loadRowData()` to talk to your server, set an instance of your class as model for your [Table](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.table.Table)'s model, and you should have a table that appears to scroll efficiently over huge sets of data. No need for pagination. Qooxdoo takes care of fetching and displaying what data is needed when it is needed where it is needed.